# Find limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)}$, if it exists

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

Continuing my practice at solving limits, I'm currently trying to solve the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)}$$

**What I've done:**

I know that since the cosine is an oscillating function, $\cos(\infty)$ doesn't converge to a single value, but I thought that, perhaps, by using trigonometric formulas and various tricks, I could bring the limit to a form that can be solved, but in vain.

Here is an attempt using the trigonometric formula $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$:

$$
\begin{align}
l
& = \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cdot \cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\right)}\cdot
    \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\cos(1)\cos(x^{-1000})-\sin(1)\sin(x^{-1000})\right)}\\
& = 0\ \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}{\left({{\cos(1)}\over{1/\cos(x^{-1000})}}-{{\sin(1)}\over{1/\sin(x^{-1000})}}\right)}\\
\end{align}
$$

**Question:**

Can the above limit be solved or it's simply *undefined*, since $\cos(\infty)$ diverges?

Comment: $\cos(1+\dfrac{x}{1000})$ is trivially bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the limit is $0$. Another elegant way to prove is using squeeze theorem.

Using $$-1 \le \cos (x) \le 1$$

We've

$$ -\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2} \le {\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)} \le \sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2} \le \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)} \le \lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}$$

$$\implies 0\le \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)} \le 0$$

$$\implies \color{blue}{\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\sqrt{x^6+5x^4+7x^2}\cos(1+x^{-1000})\right)}=0}$$

Comment: after the inequality you can simply invoque the squeeze theorem

Comment: @gimusi Yes, that's exactly what I have used to arrive to the answer

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yes it is the best solution, just invoking it make the presentation more short and clear in my opinion, but it is absolutely fine (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JaideepKhare. Your solution is simple and understandable. Also +1 for having Iron Man as your profile photo 

Comment: @AngelPolitis So you are a MCU fan too? If yes, why don't you join [Marvellous Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72766/marvellous-room)!

Comment: Marvel fan in general  I'll surely do.

Comment: This is way too complicated. We have a function $\to 0$ times a bounded function. The limit in such a case is always $0,$ no work required.

Comment: @zhw. I've added unnecessary steps to help OP in understanding my solution. This solution is also short, and not at all complicated. Why did you downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if wrong :

For $|x| \lt 1:$

$ 0\le  |\sqrt{(x^6+5x^4+7x^2)} |\cdot $

$|\cos(1+x^{-1000})|\le 4|x|.$

The limit $x \rightarrow 0$ is?

Used :

1) $|\cos(\theta) | \le 1.$

2) $x^6 + 5x^4+ 7x^2 \le $

$x^2 + 5x^2+ 7x^2 \le 16x^2$ for $|x| \lt 1.$

Comment: I’ve a doubt on the first inequality, $\cos$ can also be negative, am I wrong?

Comment: Gimusi. Took the absolute values.Thanks , I put double.

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks for pointing out. OK now?

Comment: Yes now it works!

Answer (score 0):

In $x\sqrt{x^4+5x^2+7}\cos(1+x^{-1000})$, the first factor tends to zero, the second to a finite value ($7$) and the third remains bounded (in $[-1,1]$).

Hence the limit is zero.

Comment: we don't need to factor out x, and maybe it should be |x|?

Comment: @gimusi: this is to help convince the OP that the radical expression tends to $0$. And yes, we can add an absolute value.

Comment: Ok but it should be stated more clearly that this is not the key point for the limit calculation, moreover for |x| I think that we have to put the absolute value, it is not an option